# Wants to get an element from 1st to last. But returns last to 1st

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

In get method, I want to get the element from first element to last. But it returns the list in reversed order (last to first element). How can I solve that problem with this code ?

```
import java.util.*;

class List {

    Customer listPtr;
    int index;

    public void add(Customer customer) {
        Customer temp = customer;
        if (listPtr == null) {
            listPtr = temp;
            index++;
        } else {
            Customer x = listPtr;
            while (x.next != null) {
                x = x.next;
            }
            x.next = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }

    public Customer get(int index) {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        int size = size();
        if (index == 0) {
            return listPtr;
        } else {
            while (size != index) {
                size--;
                temp = temp.next;
                System.out.println(size + "------" + index);
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}

class DemoList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List list = new List();
        Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "A");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "B");
        Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "C");
        Customer c4 = new Customer("10014", "D");
        Customer c5 = new Customer("10015", "E");
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);
        list.add(c4);
        System.out.println(list.get(1));
        //list.printList();

    }
}

class Customer {

    String id;
    String name;
    Customer next;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        Customer c = (Customer) ob;
        return this.id.equals(c.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new List class when you can use Java's Collections like ArrayLists and such?

Comment: If I were implementing a List in java, I would not require that the objects in the list be aware of the other objects - I would not have a 'next' field in the Customer object. But it is possible that your exercise requires this. Can you post the actual question you are trying to answer?

Answer (score 2):

the question is somewhat ambiguous.
it looks like you're asking why .get() isn't returning the expected element?

```
while (size != index) {
    size--;
    temp = temp.next;
    System.out.println(size + "------" + index);
}
return temp;
```

appears to be the culprit. your loop counter is decrementing from size() to desired index
while your reference is moving forward through the list.
This means that the value of size bears no real resemblance to what index you're looking at.

I'd use

```
int i =0;
while(++i <= index && i < size){
    temp = temp.next;
}
if (i == index) {
   return temp
} else {
   //off the end, so throw exception
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid doing the OP's homework for him/her.  It is best to give hints rather than solutions ... and allow the OP to *learn* by working it out for him/herself.

Comment: Using this, can't get the last element

Comment: I didn't see the comment about it being an assignment until after I'd posted.

@user2596183 with what I've given you already, you should be able to work out how to resolve that issue. good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, it is not appropriate (or in your interest in the long-term) to give you a solution ...

The basic problem is that your `get(i)` method is not returning the value a position `i`.

That should be enough of a Hint to allow you to figure out what it is really doing ... and hence to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing something very simple in a very complicated way.

I suggest:

First, remove the 'next' field from Customer.

Then, don't bother writing your own List class. Java has several perfectly good List implementations.

Example:

import java.util.*;
class DemoList {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "A");
    Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "B");
    Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "C");
    Customer c4 = new Customer("10014", "D");
    Customer c5 = new Customer("10015", "E");
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c4);

    //first customer:
    System.out.println(list.get(0)); //zero-based

    //all customers:
    for (Customer c : list) {
       System.out.println(c);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: He is implementing a linked list from scratch *as an exercise*.

Comment: Yes, I saw that comment after I'd already written the answer. However, it is an important point - coding in the real world, you use all the tools available to you, you don't re-invent the wheel. The OP did not originally state that it was an exercise, therefore I answered with the assumption it was real-world.

Comment: NickJ - when you've been here longer, you will get to recognize the signs of a "learning exercise".